# Print the ASCII Code page

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, printable-ascii

## Goal

You have to print the ASCII printable characters' code page (0x20-0x7E).
The output should look like this:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./
0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmno
pqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

## Rules

- The output should be **exactly** like shown above, but trailing whitespace is OK.
- **No builtins that trivialize the question** *(e.g. the ones that print the ASCII table)* **!** They can be posted for documentation purposes, but will not be in the leaderboards.
- Standard rules for I/O and loopholes apply.
- Lowest bytecount wins.

### Good Luck!

*P.S. This challenge is well-known, but a straight "print every single printable ASCII character" has somehow never been done here.*

Comment: Are we allowed to use built in function that check if a character is printable?

Comment: @mousetail I'd say yes.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "No builtins"? No builtins if they return exactly that output? No builtins that return any kind of ASCII table? No builtins at all (which would make this impossible in most languages)?

Comment: @pxeger no builtins that return the ascii table (the ones that trivialize the question)

Comment: Many built-ins for the ascii table seem to include characters like the line break and tab so I think they wouldn't work anyways.

Comment: Should the bottom corner be a DEL character?

Comment: @Adám No, since it's not printable.

Comment: _trivialize the question_ is not objectively defined. If a builtin outputs the string of ASCII codes (not formatted as a table), does that trivialize the question? If it outputs an ASCII table with a different format?

Comment: Is a trailing space accepted, to make the last line the same length as the others?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, it trivializes the question. A trailing space is OK but not necessary.

Comment: It may be bending the rules to almost breaking point but since 0x7F is non-printable, can it be counted as a trailing whitespace character?

Comment: @ElPedro IDK for general rules, but in the Unicode list (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) 0x7F is not present, so I wouldn't consider it as whitespace.

Comment: `0x7F` is definitely printable in CP437, and stopping at `0x7E` instead of `0x7F` does make the challenge slightly less trivial.

Comment: @640KB The challenge asks for all printable characters on ASCII, not on CP437 (which is a superset of ASCII).

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85088/107299)

Comment: @Seggan oops, didn't see that! (it didn't show up to me). But my question is different because of the required newline separators, as it requires a table and not a list. Therefore, this challenge is more complex, that (I hope) makes it different enough.

Comment: @loggeek no it doesnt

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
print(('%c'*16+'\n')*6%(*range(32,127),9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0NdNVldy9BMWz0mT11Ty0xVQ6soMS89VcPYSMfQyFxTx1JT8/9/AA)

Includes a trailing tab on the last line and a trailing newline.

Comment: `print` have another extra `\n`. So it actually ends with `\r\n\n` on Linux or `\r\r\n\r\n` on Windows. If multiple line breaks are allowed at the ending, you may simply output triple line breaks at the end.

Comment: Nice! `%c` is a proper game changer here.

Comment: `\n` alongside `\r\n` definitely looks cheaty to me. But if I were OP which I am not I'd argue a space should be perfectly fine. If the gap weren't at the end but at the beginning or in the middle of a row one clearly would want a placeholder there. Why should the end be different?

Comment: @loopywalt it's okay.

Comment: Pretty sneaky putting a tab at the end instead of a space to save one character.

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
for i in range(95):print(chr(i+32),end='\n'[~i%16:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9JU06qgKDOvRCM5o0gjU9vYSFMnNS/FVj0mTz26LlPV0MwqVvP/fwA)

Comment: Very clever use of slicing to vary the end-of-line character.  I'd give this an upvote except somebody else has a shorter Python solution.

Comment: @MarkRansom you can upvote any answers you find clever or interesting!

Answer (score 12):

## [Prelude](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), <sup><s>50</s></sup> 42 bytes

```
88+
6(1-) v^^(  1-++!)^6-!)
1- v+(1-) v(1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKzSlNSf3/38JCm8tMw1BXU6EsLk5DQcFQV1tbUTPOTFdRk8tQV6FMGyIHJP//BwA)

#### Explanation

```
88+
6(1-)
1- v+
```

Push \$16\$ to Voice 1 and \$95\$ to Voice 3.

```
       v^^
      (1-)
```

For each value from \$95\$ down to \$1\$, push that value and two copies of \$16\$ to Voice 2. When the loop ends, the stack in Voice 2 is `[..., 0, 0, 0, 95, 16, 16, 94, 16, 16, ..., 1, 16, 16]`.

```
         (  1-++!     )
```

For each triplet of values in Voice 2, sum them and subtract \$1\$, then print the result as an ASCII character...

```
                 )
          v(1-
```

in groups of 16...

```
                  ^6-!
```

with a newline appended to each group.

Printing fails on the (non-existent) 96th character because the triplet of values summed is `[0, 0, 0]`, with the result that the code attempts to convert \$-1\$ to ASCII and thus exits with an out-of-range error.

---

## [Fugue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fugue)

[image: Fugascii]

Fugue is a musical encoding for Prelude. *Fugascii**, a short trio for woodwinds, was generated from the Prelude code above using a script that I wrote for this purpose. Read all about it in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242799/92901).

<sup>* The title is a pun on a previous Fugue composition of mine, [*Fugacity*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242799/92901).</sup>

Comment: Now I want to hear the music!

Comment: @emanresuA I transcribed it here: https://t.pxeger.com/files/Fugascii.mscz. You can listen to it [on YouTube](https://youtu.be/yd-WsWzI8vk) (or see it [on Musescore.com](https://musescore.com/user/50183447/scores/8291687?share=copy_link)). It doesn't sound very good.

Comment: @pxeger That's cool! I think the clarinet part needs to be transposed down a tone to sound as intended (it's not much improvement though). I wrote it at transposed rather than concert pitch, which admittedly would be more obvious if I'd put in key signatures.

Comment: Now I want to see a whole challenge around the idea of "best sounding solution", though [tag:popularity-contest] seems to be out of fashion nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 26 bytes

```
printf %s {\ ..~}|fold -16
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuha7Cooy80rSFFSLFapjFPT06mpr0vJzUhR0Dc0gCqDqYOoB)

Comment: I was curious if this worked in bash as well: it doesn't.  Bash supports range-expansions like `{A..z}` which include some non-alphanumeric characters in the expansion, but not a range starting or ending with a space or punctuation.

Answer (score 7):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), <s>87</s> 82 bytes (3×28=84 codels)

*Thanks @Bubbler for -5 bytes by changing `4 dup * 2 *` to a more space efficient `8 4 *`*

```
eeeumtqcsqrrjlvuddtrjcqdjes_eeeu ?????rr?jujrnvmsjiqqc _eeuu kdvtrbbbbb???vv   qq?
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxVTdEKwjAM_Jc8X6FZV237K6MPMisMpg6mT-K_m2QyWHOQXi65-9D4vDYqw8BnbIhghkcPjgjSOqmEE1iVTuFtInKvLOlRAKeKg0mW0QFqJC2JqET2NCmogcZZoF3tRnHzyZZrsdwfsdtr5T_MK22kVtDaFirknCPQPN3lz16esLaOVG6XeW2g6bG8X6LR9wfYpTr-)

Might add a more detailed explanation later if I feel like to, but here's an explanation image generated by Bubbler's Piet interpreter for now. Can 100% be golfed, but I'm too lazy to do that right now lol.

#### Explanation image

[image]
The basic algorithm is to initially push `32` to the stack, then keep incrementing and outputting the character until `127`, after which the code stops. At each iteration, it checks if the number+1 is a multiple of 16, and prints a newline if it is.

#### Longer explanation

Here's the ascii piet version of the code, with newlines added for clarity:

```
eeeumtqcsqrrjlvuddtrjcqdjes_
eeeu ?????rr?jujrnvmsjiqqc _
eeuu kdvtrbbbbb???vv   qq?
```

I'll be going over the code section by section.

Initialization:

```
eeeum
eeeu
eeuu
```

Push 8, Push 4, multiply. This puts `32` onto the stack (the codepoint for space)

Top half of the loop:

```
     tqcsqrrjlvuddtrjcqdje
```

What it does:

```
Commands                              Stack          DP,     CC
dup                                   [32,32]        right   left
out (char)                            [32]           right   left
1 + Dup                               [33,33]        right   left
4 dup * dup * 2 / 1 -                 [33,33,127]    right   left
- ! !                                 [33,1]         right   left
DP+                                   [33]           down    left
```

Basically, it adds `1` to the current codepoint and checks if it is equal to `127`. If it is, then `DP+` will turn the pointer `0` times and terminate the code. Otherwise, `DP+` will turn the pointer `1` time and continue the loop.

Bottom right portion of the loop:

```
            ?jujrnvmsjiqqc
               ???vv   qq?
```

What it does:

```
Command                              Stack          DP,     CC
dup                                  [33,33]        down    left
4 dup *                              [33,33,16]     left    right
%                                    [33,1]         left    right
! 3 *                                [33,0]         left    right
1 CC+                                [33,0]         left    left
DP+                                  [33]           left    right
```

This checks if the current codepoint is a multiple of 16 (remember that we added 1 to the codepoint in the top half of the loop). If it is a multiple of 16, then `DP+` will turn the DP to face downwards. Otherwise, the DP stays facing left. This is based on the observation that all the characters before a newline all have codepoints that are 1 less than a multiple of 16.

For example, let's say that at the beginning of this portion, the stack is `[48]`. This means that the ascii `47`, or `/`, just got printed, and then that value was incremented by `1` from the top half of the loop. After taking this value modulo 16 and applied `!` on the value, the stack becomes `[48,1]`. The `1` on the stack is then multiplied by `3` which causes `DP+` to turn the DP 3 times, resulting in the DP facing down.

Bottom branch of the loop:

```
     t
     ?
     kdvtrbbbbb
```

What it does:

```
Command                              Stack          DP,     CC
1 5 dup +                            [33,1,10]      left    right
out (char) pop                       [33]           left    right
```

Basically just prints out a newline.

Top branch of the loop:

```
     t    rr
     ?????rr?
```

Nothing actually happens here. The code just passes through and enters back into the loop. One thing to note is that the reason why we did `CC+` earlier was to get through the `r` block. Before the `CC+`, the CC was facing right, but that poses a problem when we go through the `r` block, because the code will continue execution through the top left of the block, which will break the entire code. Instead, we toggle the CC once to switch it to the left, which causes the code to exit out of the block from the bottom left.

Once the top half is entered again, `dup out (char)` is ran, printing out another character, and the loop continues.

Loop exit:

```
                          s_
                           _
```

Once the loop reaches `127`, the loop is exited. `s` is essentially a noop that does nothing, and the program terminates in the `_` block.

Comment: `8 4 *` (or `4 8 *`) can certainly utilize the black area better.

Comment: @Bubbler Yep thanks for the suggestion, I was originally planning to do two rows so I wrote it like that, but I couldn't fit everything in.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
write(intToUtf8(32:126,T),1,16,,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVIzOvJCQ/tCTNQsPYyMrQyEwnRFPHUMfQTEdHSUnz/38A)

Answer (score 6):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 58 bytes

```
||for i in' '..''{print!("{:
<1$}",i,i as usize%16/15+1)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMGmtDyF3MTMPA3NaoWc1BKFNAXbpaUlaboWN61qatLyixQyFTLz1BXU9fTU69WrC4oy80oUNZSqrbhsDFVqlXQydTIVEosVSoszq1JVDc30DU21DTVrISYst1ZI09CsVYDwFiyA0AA)

### Explanation

- The answer is a closure expression implementing the `Fn()` trait.
- `print!` can pad outputs to a given length: `print!("{:x<5}", 'a')` → `axxxx`
- The length can come from an argument: `print!("{:x<1$}", 'a', 5)` → `axxxx`
- The padding char can be a raw newline in place of the `x` in this example.
- In my program, the length is either 1 (just the char) or 2 (char + newline).

Comment: If you remove `fn main(){` this would be shorter than mine

Comment: It would end up being a "snippet" I think. I can't dig up the relevant Meta link right now but we tend to expect answers to be either full programs or function definitions / lambda expressions (so `puts("Hello world!");` is not a valid C answer, but `f(){puts("Hello world!");}` is).

Comment: oh, this is sort of relevant https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet

Answer (score 6):

## MS-DOS (.COM format), <s>33</s> <s>30</s> 26 bytes

- -3 thanks to Deadcode
- -4 by using `INT 29H` to output

Iterates through 20H and 7EH, printing each character and a line break between the 16th character of each line.

```
0000 B0 20 CD 29 40 3C 7F 74 10 A8 0F 75 F5 50 B0 0A
0010 CD 29 B0 0D CD 29 58 EB E9 C3
```

Assembly version (TASM):

```
IDEAL
P8086

MODEL   TINY
CODESEG
ORG 100H

MAIN:   
    MOV  AL,20H ; Start at ' '
PRINT:
    INT  29H    ; Print character
    INC  AX     ; Increment character
    CMP  AL,7FH ; Done?
    JZ   DONE   ; Yes, exit
    TEST AL,0FH ; End of line?
    JNZ  PRINT  ; No, next character
    PUSH AX     ; Save current character
    MOV  AL,0AH ; Print CR+LF
    INT  29H
    MOV  AL,0DH
    INT  29H
    POP  AX     ; Restore current character
    JMP  PRINT  ; Next character
DONE:
    RET

END MAIN
ENDS
```

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by changing `INC DL` to `INC DX` and replacing the `XCHG`s with `PUSH` and `POP`.

Comment: Filling a buffer and printing that is another approach; 27 bytes for that as a [Linux 32-bit executable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249393).  (Perhaps less as a function).  Might be possible with `xchg ax,dx` / `stosw` to store a 2-byte newline.  But without being sure you have some stack space above you can overwrite (which would break ret), it's less appealing.

Comment: Very cool optimization of using the undocumented INT 29h for output. It's worth noting that it prints directly to the screen and can't be redirected (unlike INT 21h.02h which uses stdout). And it really was undocumented; it's not present in my 1991 copy of The Programmer's PC Sourcebook.

Comment: @Deadcode I find that [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html) is pretty useful for stuff like this.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @pxeger*

```python
for i in range(6):print(''.join(chr(j+i*16+32)for j in range(16-i//5)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw0zTqqAoM69EQ11dLys/M08jOaNII0s7U8vQTNvYSBOkOguh2tBMN1Nf31RTU/P/fwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```
for i in range(6):print bytearray(j+i*16+32for j in range(16-i/5))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN53S8osUMhUy8xSKEvPSUzXMNK0KijLzShSSKktSE4uKEis1srQztQzNtI2NQEqzEEoNzXQz9U01NSEmQQ2EGQwA)

Based on @mousetail's solution; submitted as my own answer by their suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

## Rust, <sup><del>74</del> <del>72</del> <del>70</del></sup> 64 bytes

```rs
(' '..'').any(|i|print!("{i}")>if i as u8%16>14{print!("
")});
```

Text contains non-printable characters so might not render correctly. @Antiip saved me some bytes.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMHqtDyF3MTMPA1NheqlpSVpuhY3HTTUFdT19NTr1TX1EvMqNWoyawqKMvNKFDWUqjNrlTTtMtMUMhUSixVKLVQNzewMTaph0lxKmrWa1lwQcxbWQugFCyA0AA)

Comment: The Rust version on TIO is too old for using `char`s in ranges. You may use [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/) instead, which also supports the [new syntax](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/01/13/Rust-1.58.0.html#captured-identifiers-in-format-strings) `print!("{i}")`.

Comment: You can abuse `all` for -5 bytes: `(' '..='~').all(|i|print!("{i}")==if(i as u8)%16>14{print!("
")});`

Comment: You can use the official Rust Playground: https://bit.ly/3zzZUXZ

Answer (score 5):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>110</s> 100 bytes

```
[S S S T    T   T   T   T   N
_Push_31][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   T   T   T   T   T   T   N
_Push_127][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_undefined_Label][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
S S _Print_as_character][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S S S S N
_Push_16][T S T T   _Modulo][S S S T    T   T   T   N
_Push_15][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   N
_If_neg_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][S S S T S T S N
_Push_10_\n][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##PYxBCoBADAPPySvyNZEF9yYo@PyaxsUeQjsZ@hzzHte57aNKEnpIiX0QzqxfgZAO0Bj823jGWOryYhi7y0@y6gU) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = 31
Start LOOP:
  n = n + 1
  If (n==127):
    Stop program with error by jumping to undefined Label
  Print n as character to STDOUT
  If (n modulo 16 < 15):
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  Print '\n'
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>64</s> 86 bytes

```
+++++[>++>++++++>+<<<-]>>++>+[-[>+<[->>+<<]]>>[-<<+>>]<+++++++++++++++[<<.+>>-]<<<.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvBCcAwDAMHMs4EQosYP5pAoRT6KGR@V8mv@kjcof4e13POcVfZStCMe6kAeHKTcBmEc9EUDAeMTNg/ATRxT52bfNUH)

No longer prints 0x7f as the last character.

With many thanks to @Jiří for the fix.

Comment: This includes 0x7F. It needs to stop at 0x7E.

Comment: Here is my way to fix it, but it comes at cost of 22 bytes: `+++++[>++>++++++>+<<<-]>>++>+[-[>+<[->>+<<]]>>[-<<+>>]<+++++++++++++++[<<.+>>-]<<<.>>]`

Comment: @Ray interesting point. The rules state that "The output should be exactly like shown above, but trailing whitespace is OK.". I interpret that as meaning that 0x7F being a non printable character (and therefore not affecting the display at least not on TIO) can be seen as a trailing whitespace. I'll leave it to OP to comment if I am wrong.

Comment: TIO was showing a (a character containing the hex values) for me (but stackexchange wouldn't let me include it in a comment). (And 0x00-0x19 are also (mostly) non-printable characters, but presumably nobody's printing those.)

Comment: 0x00-0x19 would be leading lines and not a trailing whitespace which would change the whole display. This answer is not going to win anyway so I'll leave it as is unless OP says otherwise. Their decision.

Comment: OP already said otherwise. See comment under question where someone is asking if the bottom corner can be DEL character (this is character 0x7F). Answer to this question was no.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>21</s> 17 bytes

-4bytes thanks to Traws!

```
`0:`c$6 16#32+!95
```

It's my first answer in K!
So there might be some optimizations ^^

```
`0:`c$6 16#32+!95
           32+!95 / Creates an array from 32 to 126
      6 16#       / Reshapes it to 16 columns and 6 lines (16 can me replaced by 0N)
   `c$            / For each elements of this array/matrix, convert the int to a char
`0:               / Print the result whitout ( and "
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJxLMLBKSFYxUzA0UzY20la0NAUAJKADsQ==)

Comment: nice first answer. you don't need the lambda and each for the conversion, just  `c$ is enough to convert the whole array.

Comment: @Traws Fixed! Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

## x86-16 machine code, PC DOS, <del>24</del> 19 bytes

```
00000000: b020 bb0a 0daa 40a8 0f75 0393 ab93 3c7e  . ....@..u....<~
00000010: 7ef3 c3                                  ~..
```

Listing:

```
B0 20           MOV   AL, 20H       ; starting codepoint
BB 0D0A         MOV   BX, 0D0AH     ; CR/LF chars
            CP_LOOP: 
AA              STOSB               ; write AL to buffer
40              INC   AX            ; increment to next char
A8 0F           TEST  AL, 0FH       ; is end of line?
75 03           JNZ   CP_NEXT       ; jump if so
93              XCHG  AX, BX        ; save current codepoint
AB              STOSW               ; write CR/LF to buffer
93              XCHG  AX, BX        ; restore codepoint
            CP_NEXT: 
3C 7E           CMP   AL, 07EH      ; <= 7EH? 
7E F3           JLE   CP_LOOP       ; if so, keep looping 
C3              RET                 ; return to caller
```

[image]

Using @PeterCordes's suggestion to write to an output buffer instead of direct to console.

Callable function, output to string buffer `ES:[DI]`.

Comment: You mean codepoint, not codepage, I think.  (BTW, I posted [a Linux x86-32 version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249393/30206) just a few minutes after this.)

Answer (score 4):

## x86-32 machine code (Linux executable) 27 bytes

cut-down NASM listing: Address | machine code | source

```
                   global _start
                   _start:            ; Linux processes (and thus static executables) start with registers zeroed, except ESP
                   asciitable:
 00 B020            mov al, ' '
 02 B20A            mov dl, 0xa
 04 89E7            mov edi, esp      ; space above ESP on the stack is argc, argv[] and env[] array elements, and the env strings.  We overwrite that.
                   .loop:
 06 AA              stosb
 07 40              inc  eax            ; there is no branch condition for AF, the half-carry flag :/
 08 A88F            test al, 0x8f       ; detect mod16 and when we've gone past printable
 0A 7503            jnz .nonewline
 0C 92              xchg  eax, edx
 0D AA              stosb
 0E 92              xchg  eax, edx
                   .nonewline:
                    ; FLAGS still set from earlier TEST
 0F 79F5            jns  .loop               ; stop at 0x80, beyond what the syscall uses
                     ; mov [edi-1], 0xa      ; no trailing newline
                   
 11 B004            mov  al, 4   ; __NR_write
                    ; ebx=0 from process startup; writing to stdin happens to work on a terminal
 13 89E1            mov  ecx, esp
 15 8D5060          lea  edx, [eax-4 + 0x7f-0x20 + 5]  ; exclusive range, 5 newlines; final line does not end with newline as whitespace isn't required
 18 CD80            int  0x80    ; write(0, ecx, 100)
                   
                   ; mov  eax,1      ; exit(ebx)
                   ; int  0x80
 1A CC              int3  ; abort program
```

Fill bytes into a buffer (overwriting stack memory above ESP, starting with argc, argv[], and into env[]).  We go a bit beyond 0x7e because that makes the stop condition cheaper, but those bytes aren't printed: we have to generate an explicit length in EDX anyway, so we just omit it.

We make one `write(0, buf, 100)` system call.  `0` is STDIN_FD, but on a normal xterm/konsole/gnome_terminal, FD 0,1, and 2 are all read+write duplicates of the same file description.  So we save 1 byte for `inc ebx`.  If you want to pipe the output into something to hexdump for example, `./asciitable 0>&1 | hexdump -C`

Instead of existing cleanly, we use `int3` to raise a debug exception, resulting in the OS delivering SIGTRAP, killing the process.  A typical shell will then print `Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`, but that's the shell, not this program.  This saves 3 bytes vs. `mov al, 1` / `int 0x80` (the upper bytes of EAX are zeroed, unless `write` returned an error).

I considered letting execution just fall off the end (to probably `00 00` padding added by the linker, which decodes as `add [eax], al` and will segfault), but we're already stretching things a bit by only counting the `.text` section of the executable, not the whole file size. (Unlike a DOS `.com`, there *is* metadata)

Our output doesn't end with a newline; as the question says, no trailing whitespace is required after the `0x7e`  `~` character.

The mod16 detection via checking the low bits 4 of AL is fairly straightforward, but was borrowed from ErikF's [the x86-16 MS-DOS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249247/print-the-ascii-code-page/249314#249314) which I read first before thinking about how I'd do it.

But to enable a `jns` as the loop branch without a separate `cmp`, we also set the MSB in our mask for `test`.  That's not a spot we wanted a newline anyway.  I'd hoped to be able to branch on FLAGS from `inc al` (2 bytes), but since we'd also need something for newlines, this is even better: we can now use `inc eax` (1 byte) and still branch on the MSB of AL.  Using mov dl, 0xa (2B) / xchg/stosb/xchg (1B each) instead of `mov byte [edi], 0xa` (3 bytes) / `inc edi` (1 byte but clobbers FLAGS) was the key to that, saving another `test` or `cmp` for a net saving of 1 byte.

Demo:

```
$ nasm -felf32 asciitable.asm
$ ld -melf_i386 -o asciitable asciitable.o
$ ./asciitable
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./
0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmno
pqrstuvwxyz{|}~Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

$ ./asciitable 0>&1 | cat  # suppresses signal diagnostic from shell
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./
0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmno
pqrstuvwxyz{|}~peter@volta:/tmp$

$ ./asciitable 0>&1 | hexdump -C
00000000  20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27  28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f  | !"#$%&'()*+,-./|
00000010  0a 30 31 32 33 34 35 36  37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e  |.0123456789:;<=>|
00000020  3f 0a 40 41 42 43 44 45  46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d  |?.@ABCDEFGHIJKLM|
00000030  4e 4f 0a 50 51 52 53 54  55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c  |NO.PQRSTUVWXYZ[\|
00000040  5d 5e 5f 0a 60 61 62 63  64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b  |]^_.`abcdefghijk|
00000050  6c 6d 6e 6f 0a 70 71 72  73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a  |lmno.pqrstuvwxyz|
00000060  7b 7c 7d 7e                                       |{|}~|
00000064

$ strace ./asciitable 0>/dev/null
execve("./asciitable", ["./asciitable"], 0x7ffc63d167c0 /* 55 vars */) = 0
[ Process PID=2670503 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
strace: WARNING: Proper structure decoding for this personality is not supported, please consider building strace with mpers support enabled.
write(0, " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./\n0123456789:;<=>"..., 100) = 100
--- SIGTRAP {si_signo=SIGTRAP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGTRAP (core dumped) +++
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVPBbhMxEL37K96tIJKQ0lagRD0gQSSkChAgcYiiyGvPbky99mJ7m01/vh17k7awh13P2H7z5s1bGSO1lT1Maxnbh4fah1YmfL5ZgQZSfZKVJVwIiGVjfSUttjHJkMT4WeDFs8SNcf2ALnhFDBvxSjqNtOsj@HQy6gVmfI2CgL1JOwRqTEwUIu4peNITPqmoYyI/vwsZlTHl0kKg9XeQdoIznI2B5mA@yDEgbfhq7E6EYicVQVb@jjIUvGM6lCurW5gIGRo1ye@79QaZLLmyCkEeQJZacilOMLZBeZfvBuOaOAN@Exg37INJxNsyzcTMet8xy5h8rASMUwDJ4V@VGClQru48qiCd2kF5p00yTI8HgI@rSSm3k7aeKiZzQG1lg8VbgUQxFQHmw4da4I@7x8x5R3trHAkMateUkiyDHp6I/JdeFrGqA/Nes2SbUcHlka824hlywemnmtLmihEofR5hjmzy/bGaeE5floa3268/tkUmwRFVw/UcdfDtySmjE/puiXyI1UXynNPGsQRdR1yRE3sfbvMAJfMJrXFMJvNluJOwq0@4xjngiDTpIuWvL99moXdHSqSGYg8BSzJ3yuGaVZle4g238L6ezod3c15fbTIee9D20bB3eEoNTXCFoypxiTozQA6gPeVhJvaHHv18PAYZsd9x36MPTXRnib3@tzeBdLZHQp7jXJykzBM6L92UaZy28/IiM2In8y/DsjVB8t/6CA) with an `inc ebx` added so it writes to stdout and thus shows up in the tio.run output pane. IDK why it didn't show in the debug pane. (32-bit code supported by having FASM make an executable directly, instead of NASM.)

### TODO: a function instead of program, filling a buffer

We'd obviously save the syscall code, but could no longer write past the end of the actual stop point.  So would need maybe 1 more byte in the loop to go back to `cmp al, 0x7e` / `jne` as the loop condition.

Comment: I really wanted to do a `jns` for the loop condition as well, but with the code*point* ending at `0x7E` not `0x7F` that made it not really work out.

Comment: @640KB: Yeah, that's part of why I went with filling a buffer, so I could go past the end but not print that part.  Also that Linux doesn't have a putchar system call so the byte(s) have to be in memory.

Comment: I suppose I could have mine write to a buffer too and save 3 bytes by using `stosb` instead of `int 29h`. Great idea!

Comment: @640KB: As I suggested for [ErikF's DOS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249247/print-the-ascii-code-page/249314#249314), you could `xchg`/`stosw`/`xchg` to store a 2-byte newline similar to how I'm doing it here.

Comment: Ha, I actually did that when I was editing my answer for the output to buffer!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

**Without builtin:**

```
₃L31+çJ6ä»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOzj7Gh9uHlXmaHlxza/f8/AA)

**With builtin (5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)):**

```
žQ6ä»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L5As8NLDu3@/x8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
₃L          # Push a list in the range [1,95]
  31+       # Add 31 to each
     ç      # Convert the codepoint-integers to ASCII characters
      J     # Join the list together to a string
       6ä   # Split it into 6 parts
         »  # Join by newlines
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)

žQ          # Push a string of all ASCII characters
  6ä»       # Same as above
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal 2.14.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
kPð+s16ẇ⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrUMOwK3MxNuG6h+KBiyIsIiIsIltdIl0=)

So turns out `kP` isn't *actually* all of printable ascii - it's missing the space character, and it isn't in the right order either, meaning that for the purposes of this challenge, it shouldn't be banned, as it doesn't print "the ascii table" and it isn't exactly "trivial" either.

(And if it isn't allowed, then that's grounds enough for VTCing this challenge as needs details or clarity, because "trivialising the challenge" isn't objectively defined - there's an argument to be made that `kPð+s` isn't a trivial built-in).

### Explained

```
kPð+s16ẇ⁋
kPð+       # a string of 0-9a-Z + python's string.punctuation + space
    s      # sorted to be in printable ascii order
     16ẇ   # split into parts of length 16
        ⁋  # joined on newlines
```

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
kP6/⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrUDYv4oGLIiwiIiwiW10iXQ==)

Bug fixes make this 5 bytes in reality.

Comment: It does not output the required text which has 6 lines of 16 characters each (except the final line which has 15). Changing `5` to `6` does not do the trick either.

Comment: `6/` should work, but it's so buggy. `16ẇ` works, though.

Comment: Bugs are fixed, you can use `6/` now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 18 bytes

```
@!~r@' +]16co)++un
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9W9t9Bsa7IQV1BO9bQLDlfU1u7NO9/4H8A)

```
@!~  # Push ! and ~ to stack
r@   # Range between them
' +] # Prepend " "
16co # Chunks of 16
)++  # Concat
un   # Intercalate newlines between blocks and join
```

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 12 bytes

```
6‿16⥊' '+↕95
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=NuKAvzE24qWKJyAnK+KGlTk1)

Output has a trailing space character.

BQN's [affine character space](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/tutorial/expression.html#character-arithmetic) is quite neat here: adding a number to a character gives another character.
So: create a range from zero to 95 (`↕95`), add it to the space character (`' '+`), and reshape to 6-row, 16-column format (`6‿16⥊`).

---

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 26 bytes

```
@+100⥊⍉(32+⍉6‿16⥊↕95)∾6⥊10
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=QCsxMDDipYrijYkoMzIr4o2JNuKAvzE24qWK4oaVOTUp4oi+NuKlijEwCg==)

Longer version with output string that is truly "**exactly** like shown above", written before the edit allowing trailing whitespace.
Creates a transposed array of character values (`32+⍉6‿16⥊↕95`), appends a newline value 10 to each column (`∾6⥊10`), re-transposes (`⍉`) & extracts the first 100 values (`100⥊`), and finally converts to characters (`@+`).

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 35 bytes

```powershell
-join(' '..'~')-split'(.{16})'-ne''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fNys/M09DXUFdT0@9Tl1Tt7ggJ7NEXUOv2tCsVlNdNy9VXf3/fwA)

```powershell
     (' '..'~')                     # create a list of characters from <space> to ~
-join                               # join the list to a single string
               -split'(.{16})'      # split the string every 16 chars ...
                              -ne'' # ... and let only non-empty strings pass.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 10 bytes

```
¬ ~5ñ16|á
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//9AahTrTwxsNzWoOL@T6/x8A)

Explanation:

```
¬               # Insert characters between the code points...
  ~             #   "space" and "~"
   5ñ           # 5 Times...
     16|        #   Go to the 16th character on this line
        á<cr>   #   Append a newline
```

Hexdump:

```
00000000: ac20 7e35 f131 367c e10d                 . ~5.16|..
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 bytes

```perl
say map$/x!($_%16).chr,32..126
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhN7FARb9CUUMlXtXQTFMvOaNIx9hIT8/QyOz//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 3):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-r`, 94 bytes

```
s/.*/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO\nPQRSTUVWXYZ/
saa !"#$%\&'()*+,-./\n0123456789:;<=>?\n@&[\\]^_\n`\L&{|}~a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WF9PS9/RydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8mLyAwKDgkNCw8IjJKn6s4MVFBUUlZRTVGTV1DU0tbR1dPPybPwNDI2MTUzNzC0sraxtbOPibPQS06JiY2Lj4mLyHGR626prYu8f//f/kFJZn5ecX/dYsA)

This is probably the best that can be done in sed, which has no functionality for ranges of characters. The main byte saving is in the fact we can generate `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` and then use `\L` to get the lowercase version.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```php
<?=chunk_split(join(range(' ','~')),16);
```

Simply outputs the expected text, without any trailing newlines.

Just run `php file.php` and it should produce the output.

Try it on: https://onlinephp.io/c/013ce

---

Thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan) for -3 bytes.

Comment: `join('',range(' ','~'))` can just be `join(range(' ','~'))` for -3 bytes

Comment: @Steffan Totally forgot to check if the empty string was required. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
intToUtf8(rbind(matrix(32:126,16),10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfWJycmRlfkpiUk2r7PzOvJCQ/tCTNQqMoKTMvRSM3saQos0LD2MjK0MhMx9BMU8fQQFPzf3JiiQaSPs3/AA)

Comment: I think that this outputs an illegal final space.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen hmmm, seems so, indeed. [Waiting for clarification.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249247/print-the-ascii-code-page/249257?noredirect=1#comment556558_249247)

Comment: Looks like it's Ok now...

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 bytes

```apl
6 16⍴' '…'~'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L@ZgqHZo94t6grqjxqWqdepg0T/FwAA)

`' '…'~'` inclusive range from space to tilde

`6 16⍴` cyclically **r**eshape into the required number of rows and columns

Comment: I think that this outputs an illegal final space.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen APL is an array language. The normal way to output multiple lines is to print an orthogonal (non-ragged) matrix, padding with spaces. Furthermore, OP has now explicitly clarified that any trailing whitespace is OK.

Comment: looks like the OP has now allowed trailing spaces, so this is now Ok.  But (as a newbie array programmer) surely it would otherwise be possible in APL to output multiple non-identically-long lines?  It was do-able in BQN (see my answer), albeit with a substantially longer program...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yes, it is possible to output multiple times, and also to output a flat character vector with line breaks in it. It just isn't the norm.

Comment: Not sure if APL has anything like J's alphabet `a.`, but perhaps this approach could  be adapted: `2}.8 16$a."_`?

Comment: @Jonah It does (`⎕AV`) but it isn't ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/calculator), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```
UnicodeToText(Flatten(Zip(If(Mod(a,16)>14,{a,10},{a}),a,32...126)))
```

Text is shown on the graph.

Might be golfable with some different strategy, but I'm not too experienced with GeoGebra.

[Try It Online!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/d9atqthe)

Comment: I think you also printed a Del character at the end, is it allowed?

Comment: @NobodyNeedsNames That is an easy fix.

Comment: Good (filler))))))))))

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
♣⌡╒T≥$y☻/n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9tYXRoZ29sZv//4pmj4oyh4pWSVOKJpSR54pi7L27//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
♣           # Push 128
 ⌡          # Decrement it by 2 to 126
  ╒         # Pop and push a list in the range [1,126]
   T        # Push 31
    ≥       # Pop and remove the first 31 items from the list
     $      # Convert each codepoint-integer to a character
      y     # Join the list to a string
       ☻    # Push 16
        /   # Pop and split the string into parts of size 16
         n  # Join the list by newlines
            # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-nr`, 39 bytes

```
[range(32;127)]|implode|scan(".{1,16}")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oq3B5tJJuXpFS7IKlpSVpuhY31aOLEvPSUzWMjawNjcw1Y2sycwty8lNSa4qTE_M0lPSqDXUMzWqVNCHKoboWQGkA)

The best I can do without regex is 40 bytes:

```
16*range(2;8)|[.+range(16-./99)]|implode
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oq3B5tJJuXpFS7IKlpSVpuhY3NQzNtIoS89JTNYysLTRrovW0ITxDM109fUtLzdiazNyCnPyUVIh6qLYFUBoA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>51</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>49</s></sup> 48 bytes

```c
f(c){for(c=32;putchar(c)<126;++c%16||puts(""));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY95T8JAEMX/91Osq@guh0qRKhS8EO/7Vga1Lr0EhtoWqZb60a1rgMQ4ySTzXuYl7ydyoqOjlSQmEzwyex4T1YKiuf1A2LoUvJJXVC2TEam8OhxK22eUcq7FiYMB6eoOMk6iKSLnN5AmRugaIjBapEoomQY6M5uam2c8ncnmFhYBl/JKYbmorqyWylqlurYOuLG5Vduu7@zu7R8cHh2fnAKenV9cXl3f3N7dPzQAmo9PgM/6i2gZpmU7r@1OF3uA7pvnB/33QfjxGQ3jL6qNOvTQD8ZNhG2ItuE1mrJKRCGsKxCWanKLNEv@6gKNR2mT8dEx4fxvexLaZBSwPqYsA6Z8QJqdYMvPOPkWZke3/CQ3@AE)

*Saved <s>a</s> 2 bytes thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)!!!*
*Saved a bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!*

Comment: 50 bytes: `c;f(){for(;c=-~c%96;c%16||puts(""))putchar(c+31);}`

Comment: Also 50 bytes: `main(c){for(;++c<97;)~putchar(30+c)%16||puts("");}` and `c;f(){++c%96&&f(~putchar(c+31)%16||puts(""));c=0;}`

Comment: Also, seems that the third one may be 49 bytes if we can allow the function not been reusable after `c` got integer overflow (\$>2^{31}-1\$): `c;f(){++c%96&&f(~putchar(c%96+31)%16||puts(""));}`

Comment: @tsh Sorry, my bad. Was doing it too quickly and didn't have a `puts("")` in between `f();f();`!

Comment: @tsh Very clever - thanks! :D

Comment: 48: `f(c){for(c=32;putchar(c)<126;++c%16||puts(""));}`

Comment: @ovs That's gone full circle back to my starting point but using the return of `putchar` in the conditional test. Brilliant - thanks! :D Also using `c` as a parameter is a great golf when `f` takes no parameters, thanks again! :)))

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＵＴ⪪⪫…· ¦~ω¹⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8kPz09JzWkKDNXQ9OaK6AoM69EI7ggJ7NEwys/M0/DMy85p7Q4syw1KDEvPVVDSUFJR0GpTklTR6EciA3NNDWt////r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＴ
```

Disable automatic padding (would normally output a trailing space on the last line).

```
⪪⪫…· ¦~ω¹⁶
```

List the characters from   to `~` inclusive, join them together, split into groups of 16, and implicitly print each group on its own line.

Save 6 bytes by using the builtin `γ` in place of `⪫…· ¦~ω`.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8kPz09JzWkKDNXQ9OaK6AoM69EI7ggJ7NEQ0lBMUZJWUVVTV1DU0tbR1dP38DQyNjE1MzcwtLK2sbWzt7B0cnZxdXN3cPTy9vH188/IDAoOCQ0LDwiMio6JiY2Lj4hMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyisqq6prZOSUfB0ExT0/r///@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: The question has since been edited to allow any trailing whitespace, in which case save 2 bytes from both programs by removing the `ＵＴ`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 36 bytes

```factor
32 126 [a,b] 16 group "\n"join write
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU2t0GBPP3crhfSi_NKCzLx0hdzEkgy9osS89NRiheLUwtLUvGQgKzNfwXppaUmarsVNFWMjBUMjM4XoRJ2kWAVDM4hWBaWYPKWs_Mw8hfKizJJUiNoFUApKAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>15</s> 9 bytes

```
jsMc6rd\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6vYN9msKCWm/v9/AA)

There's a literal DEL character after the `\`.

```
jsMc6rd\
     rd\  Half-inclusive string range from ' ' (space) to DEL
   c6     Chop into 6 equal-sized lists (last chunk is smaller)
 sM       Join each list on '' (empty)
j         Join on newlines, implicitly output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 33 bytes

```
.say for (' '..'~').join.comb(16)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1@vOLFSIS2/SEFDXUFdT0@9Tl1TLys/M08vOT83ScPQTPP/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
P*C:32,127<>16u
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIlAqQzozMiwxMjc8PjE2dSIsIiIsIiIsIiJd)

#### Explanation

```
P*C:32,127<>16u
    32,127       Range(32, 127)
          <>16   Group into chunks of size 16 (with the last one being shorter)
  C:             Convert to characters
P*               Print each sublist (concatenated together, by default)
              u  Suppress autoprinting of the last expression
```

Or, with the `-l` flag to handle the output formatting, it would be 12 bytes:

```
C:32,127<>16
```

#### Using built-in

`PA` is a string containing all printable ASCII characters, so:

```
PA<>16Jn
```

Or, with the `-l` flag:

```
PA<>16
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>53</s> 44 bytes

*Thanks [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) for telling me about `each_slice`, saving 9 bytes!*

```ruby
(' '..'~').each_slice(16).each{|x|puts x*""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X0NdQV1PT71OXVMvNTE5I744JzM5VcPQDMKtrqmoKSgtKVao0FJSqv3/HwA)

My first time golfing in Ruby lol, just wanted to try a new language :D . Tell me if there are any golfs, I'm anticipating a lot!

Comment: `'~'` can be `?~`, and you can use `_1` instead of `x` and `|x|` if you use a newer version, like on [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWNzUKSkuKFTTUFdT19OzrNPVSE5Mz4otzMpNTNQzNNPVyEwuq4w21lJRqIeqh2mDaAQ)

Comment: `.each` isn't needed; you can pass the block directly to `each_slice`: [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN1U01BXU9fTs6zT1UhOTM-KLczKTUzUMzTSrC0pLihXiDbWUlGohaqFaYFoB). A [port](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboW-1XsbGyilVSLlbQMzWK1zLRU9FWjtdQV1PX07Ot0CmIhqqCKYZoA) of xnor's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249282/92901) is shorter though.

Answer (score 2):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 23 bytes

```
95:>32+16 chunk chr out
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/39LUys7YSNvQTCE5ozQvG0gWKeSXlvz/DwA)

Slightly shorter than the more obvious 24 bytes:

```
32 126|>16 chunk chr out
```

### Explanation

```
95:>32+16 chunk chr out
95:>                       the range of numbers from 0 to 94 inclusive
    32+                    add 32 to each
       16 chunk            split into chunks of 16
                chr        convert each number to a character
                    out    output it
```

stacked's default output behavior with `out` for 2D character arrays is exactly joining them, and produces the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a -s=`, 45 bytes

```
[ -/]|
|[0-?]|
|[@-O]|
|[P-_]|
|[`-o]|
|[p-~]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdW20km6iko6Ckm6xrVLsgqWlJWm6Fjd1oxV09WNruGqiDXTtwbSDrj-YDtCNB9MJuvlgukC3LhaiCap3AZQGAA)

#### Explanation

The `-a` flag requests all possible matches; the `-s=` flag sets the separator between matches to empty string. Then the regex is just a big alternation: "match any character from   to `/`, or a newline, or any character from `0` to `?`, or a newline, or..." The regex always matches one character, and the `-a` flag outputs all of them.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck) + head + sh, 65 + 10 bytes

```
>-[-[-<]>>+<]>->++++++[->>++++[-<++++>]<[-<<.+>>]++++++++++.[-]<]
```

Execute `<brainfuck-program>|head -c-2` (see [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10118)).

`head` removes a trailing `\del` char of the brainfuck program output  (as noted by [@mousetail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91213/mousetail)).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70yqSgxMy-tNDl7wYKlpSVpuhY3He10o4HQJtbOThtI6Nppg0G0rp0dhLYBUXaxNkCWjZ62nV2sNhzoRevG2sRCDIKaBzMXAA)

Comment: This prints `\del` at the end, which is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 59 bytes (4×26=104 codels)

```
tliusqrfvrtqqqqijsmva???Bt  t?sd???vmjftrqaaaaqrsb_t eTt ee
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJyljcEKwjAQRP9lzxPINlXT_ErpQWqEQtVC9CT-u7OVSO9NBja7M_vylvFxyZL63uMI9TggoEUDDVAWz-Z36UV6qpwro7GKVjeA-9qZvA2ZazYR24qG9ES263qV_RVWSPxDTqiwHdrQTLtxA6TkRZI45wQyTze-1fOwy2WUdD3PJUOm-_J60pPPF4PRSYA)

[image]

#### How it works

```
4 dup * dup +         Initialize n to 32
Loop:
    dup outC          [n] Print as char
    1 + dup dup       [n n n] Add 1 and make two more copies
    4 dup * % !       [n n n%16==0] Is this number divisible by 16?
    CC+               [n n] If so,
        5 dup + outC        Print newline
    5 dup dup * * >   [n n>125] Is this number greater than 125?
    ! DP+             [n] If not, go back to start of Loop
outC                  Otherwise, print n (126) and exit
```

Comment: I thought my Piet answer was pretty good. Lol nope

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), <s>80</s> <s>72</s> 56 bytes

#### 56 bytes versuin

```kotlin
(' '..'~').chunked(16).flatMap{it+"\n"}.joinToString("")
```

Directly using a char range instead of an integer range.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDkAwEADQX2m69C6SSyz@wsRoaVBO6ypyJuHXy9tfzJpYSrjE7J4F0NzHyaJJoIAzjsi9DmlcL4nzBHWDFJLX1h83a2UHsQ9tmaXPnf5vAWux4FM@)

#### 72 bytes version

```kotlin
(32..126).chunked(16).flatMap{it.map{it.toChar()}+"\n"}.joinToString("")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcw9CoAwDEDhq0inBCGgghdwdtLRpfgbralIOknPXgWn903v8OpY0hIkOy0LYPZcN4s6gQRVSVSUNdK4BTnmCYrPi7Pa2uthpfOP@mazN2DMzSAm0u5Zet/p91nBGEwY0ws)

#### 80 bytes version

```kotlin
(32..126).chunked(16){it.joinToString(""){""+it.toChar()}+"\n"}.joinToString("")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zco7CoAwDADQq0imhEJBBS/gEXR0EX@Nn1QknUrPXt1dH@/werLkNUhxjSxIRbwfFj0FM9aVtWXVkJ1ckGOZsWwostrds/S@0y9uCEARwHysvnXjg5QMDALp1zKl/AI)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7.5 bytes (15 nibbles)

```
`/16+' '`,95
```

```
`/16+' '`,95
        `,95    # range from 0 to 95
    +' '        # add each to a space character
`/16            # and split into chunks of 16
```

[image]

---

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
`/16>>`<@
```

Uses the special value assigned to `@` when input is empty, corresponding to a list of ascii characters including newline, in a non-standard order.

````
`/16>>`<@
        @       # " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,!?_"
                # + newline +
                # "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-+:;\"'~`@#$%^&*()[]{}<>\\/=|"
      `<        # sort 
    >>          # remove first item (newline)
`/16            # and split into chunks of 16
```
````

Answer (score 2):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 50 bytes

```
i<C-r>=joi<Tab>m<Tab>r<Tab>32,126),'"<C-v><C-v>".v:val'),"")
<Esc>qq16|a
<Esc>q4@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P1PINis/kzOXs4jT2EjH0MhMU0ddSUxMSa/MqiwxR11TR0lJk0u6sNDQrCYRSJs4FP7/DwA)

[As pointed out by @Ray](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249247/print-the-ascii-code-page/249309?noredirect=1#comment583576_249309), if you have version 8.1.26 or newer, you'll have to replace `r<Tab>` with `rang<Tab>` for 53 bytes.

#### Explanation

```
i<C-r>=                                                       # Insert the result of:
               m<Tab>             ,                    )      #   Map...
                                   '"<C-v><C-v>".v:val'       #     Convert to char...
                     r<Tab>32,126)                            #     over range [32,126]
       joi<Tab>                                         ,"")  #   Join with empty strings
<Esc>
     qq                                                       # Record macro @q:
       16|                                                    #   Go to 16th character
          a                                                   #   Add a newline
<Esc>q
      4@q                                                     # Run macro @q 4 times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 43 bytes

```
for(i=1,95,printf("%c",i+31);i%16||print())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN7XT8os0Mm0NdSxNdQqKMvNK0jSUVJOVdDK1jQ01rTNVDc1qasDiGpqaEC1QnTATAA)

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 44 bytes

```
for(i=2,7,print(Strchr([s=16*i..s+15-i\7])))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN3XS8os0Mm2NdMx1Cooy80o0gkuKkjOKNKKLbQ3NtDL19Iq1DU11M2PMYzU1NSF6oFphRgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>72</s> 63 bytes

```clj
(doseq[x(range 32 127)](print(str(char x)({15 \
}(rem x 16)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMlvzi1MLpCoygxLz1VwdhIwdDIXDNWo6AoM69Eo7ikSCM5I7FIoUJTo9rQVCGGq1ajKDVXoULB0EwTBP7/BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 19 bytes

```
6*$(16*1¶
Y`1` -~_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8tMS0XD0EzL8NA2rsgEwwQF3br4//8B) Explanation:

```
6*$(16*1¶
```

Insert 6 rows of 16 `1`s.

```
Y`1` -~_
```

Cyclically transliterate the first 95 `1`s to the range from   to `~` and delete the 96th.

Comment: The question has since been edited to allow any trailing whitespace, in which case save 1 byte removing the `_`, which makes the transliteration wrap around so that the 96th `1` transliterates to ` ` again.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
↓2C16mcŀ127
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbZCNnQ7Pc5KMNhkbm//8DAA)

```
       ŀ127 # range from zero to 126
     mc     # map across this & get characters
  C16       # cut into sublists with length 16
↓2          # drop the first 2 of them
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
'~':16e!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X71O3crQLFXx/38A) Outputs a trailing whitespace (to make the last row have the same length as the others).

#### How it works

```
'~'   % Push this character
:     % Range from space to that character, including both. Gives a character vector
16e   % Format as a 16-row character matrix, in major-column order. Pads with
      % character 0 at the end
!     % Transpose
      % Implicit display. Character 0 is displayed as space
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
l=''.join(chr(x+32)for x in range(95))
while l:print l[:16];l=l[16:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8dWXV0vKz8zTyM5o0ijQtvYSDMtv0ihQiEzT6EoMS89VcPSVFOTqzwjMydVIceqoCgzr0QhJ9rK0CzWOsc2J9rQzCr2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
32r126Ọs⁴Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/YqMjQyOzh7p7iR41bIv//BwA)**

5 if we can just use our langauage's features:

```
ØṖs⁴Y
```

#### How?

```
32r126Ọs⁴Y - Link: no arguments
32         - 32                }
   126     - 126               }
  r        - inclusive range   }
      Ọ    - cast to ordinals  } - together this is the same as ØṖ yields
        ⁴  - 16
       s   - split into chunks of length (up to 16)
         Y - join with newline characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 102 bytes

```
00000000: 5350 5452 5651 5553 d7d0 d4d2 d6d1 d5d3  SPTRVQUS........
00000010: e732 3034 3236 3135 33b7 b0b4 b2b6 b1b5  .20426153.......
00000020: b3e7 7270 7472 7671 7573 f7f0 f4f2 f6f1  ..rptrvqus......
00000030: f5f3 e70a 080c 0a0e 090d 0b8f 888c 8a8e  ................
00000040: 898d 8be7 4a48 4c4a 4e49 4d4b cfc8 ccca  ....JHLJNIMK....
00000050: cec9 cdcb e72a 282c 2a2e 292d 2baf a8ac  .....*(,*.)-+...
00000060: aaae a9ad 0300                           ......
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc9LMgRBFIXhuVWcIY2KW/eRmWUFtEegMc@nCRE0bfslRXcEPXAW8MV/0iall/q8eZ1n2u0MJkYwNYY5G2FmguILoWhhFFdGFCsCrG4f7p/uHlfDbgdbYexG9cIQEoWwOMgoBpHkkSgpEieHNCYDBiZlN5rsG9yNJNXDsyd49Qzv/AhvXtB8IzRtjOba2I1h/fa5/nrffOwZ0o1mTXoMRVCgDIpUQRMVUAoNIYSMEEP9Mfa3M7QbYQoFIfUYjRqgWSO06gQtmpBbDsg5x62xPL9a3lxcX/4xrBu55gm55NRjOIIDZ3DkCp64gFNsiCHmXcfi8GQxHJ0e/xquGzHGijjFHi9E@H/bB/P8DQ)

For some reason, compressing it made it actually a bit larger than the original string.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 63 bytes

```js
for(i=33,a=' ';i<129;a+=Buffer([i++]))i%16||console.log(a,a='')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN-3T8os0Mm2NjXUSbdUV1K0zbQyNLK0TtW2dStPSUos0ojO1tWM1NTNVDc1qapLz84rzc1L1cvLTNRJBGtQ1IcZATYOZCgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 65 bytes

```
_#[]=[]
n#x=take n x:n#drop n x
main=putStr$unlines$16#[' '..'~']
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWNx3jlaNjbaNjufKUK2xLErNTFfIUKqzylFOK8gtATK7cxMw824LSkuCSIpXSvJzMvNRiFUMz5Wh1BXU9PfU69ViIQVDzYOYCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 52 bytes

```forth
: f 127 32 do i emit i 16 mod 15 = if cr then loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcXRCYAwDEDBVd4CfrSiguI0trEFa6Rk/6j3c6LdynDKn/uKEOLCGElKJbdqX2GmaSJM7FTh6FjJN5fqw@aCvw)

### Explanation

Loops from 32 to 127 (end is non-inclusive). Outputs the ascii char for each number, if index % 16 == 15, outputs a newline.

### Code Explanation

```forth
: f            \ start a new word definition
  127 32       \ set up loop bounds
  do           \ start a new counted loop
    i emit     \ output the ascii character for the current loop index
    i 16 mod   \ get index modulo 16
    15 =       \ check if result is equal to 15
    if cr then \ if it is, output a newline
  loop         \ end the counted loop
 ;             \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 67 bytes

```python
Count i while i-100 {
1/((i+1)%17+1)
Write 10*_+(i+32-i/17)*(1-_)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/985vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIVPXTKGaCyKWBRXL0jU0087UNwVKhBdllgAVaQEFjI20s7hqoSKGBly1//8DAA)

#### Explanation

We run a single loop that outputs one character each time, using math to switch between ASCII characters and newlines.

The loop index `i` runs from 0 through 99. We want to print newlines at indices 16, 33, 50, 67, and 84--that is, where `(i+1)%17` is zero. With no comparison operators in *Acc!!*, we use integer division instead: when `(i+1)%17` is zero, `1/((i+1)%17+1)` is one, and it is zero otherwise. We store this quantity in the accumulator.

Now if the accumulator value is one, we want to write a newline, and if it is zero, we want to write something else. This is easily accomplished by multiplying the two quantities by `_` and `(1-_)` respectively, and adding the results: `Write 10*_+(...)*(1-_)`. It only remains to calculate the ASCII character's codepoint. At first, it is just `i+32`, but we need to adjust for the newlines. The number of newlines printed so far is `i/17`, so subtracting this from the index gives us the correct codepoint formula: `i+32-i/17`.

---

A more straightforward solution with two loops is 73 bytes:

```python
Count i while i-6 {
Count j while j-16+i/5 {
Write i*16+32+j
}
Write 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), 53 bytes

```
e9*&1f+2*   v
v;?=&:&:+1o:<
\:1f+%?!`   /
        `ao
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/z/VUkvNME3bSEtBQaGMq8za3lbNSs1K2zDfyoYrxgooo2qvmACU0@dSgIKExPz//wE)

Unfortunately, I feel like a lot of these bytes are spent setting, storing, and checking if we're at `126` yet, but I'm unsure of a better way of accomplishing this.

```
e9*&            push 126 to the stack, and pop it into a register
    1f+2*       push 32 to the stack
            v   Change IP direction downwards

            <   Change IP direction to the left
          o:    Duplicate the top of the stack, then pop it to STDOUT as a char
       :+1      Add one to the value on the top of the stack, and duplicate it
    &:&         Pop the register back onto the stack, duplicate it, then pop that into the register
 ;?=            If our two duplicated values match, end execution
v               Change IP direction downwards

\               Mirror IP to the right
 :              Duplicate the top of the stack
  1f+           Put 16 on the stack
     %          Get the modulus of our counter and 16
      ?!`       If the result is 0, drop down a line, and 
         ao         Print a newline
        `           And raise back up a line
            /   Else, mirror the IP up
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$17\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 13.993 bytes

**Without printable ascii builtin**

```
nOC+32r95 16'+xcn
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJuT0MrMzJyOTUgMTYnK3hjbiIsIiJd)

**With printable ascii builtin \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.231 bytes**

```
ncp16'+xcn
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJuY3AxNicreGNuIiwiIl0=)

```
nOC+32r95 16'+xcn
      r95          # range [0,95)
   +32             # add 32 to each, range [32,126)
  C                # convert each element to str
 O                 # join by nothing
n         16       # every 16th element, apply the function
            '+     # add
               cn  # newline
              x    # to the element

ncp16'+xcn
 cp                # printable ascii
n  16'+xcn         # same as above
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>69</s> 63 bytes

```julia
map(i->println(String(reshape([' ':'~';' '],(16,6))[:,i])),1:6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PzexQCNT166gKDOvJCdPI7gEyEjXKEotzkgsSNWIVldQt1KvU7cG0rE6GoZmOmaamtFWOpmxmpo6hlZmmv//AwA)

-6 bytes thanks to @amelies: `' ':'~'` is a valid range in Julia; no need to convert from integers

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```julia
0:16:80 .|>n->(prod(' ':'~')*" ")[n+1:n+16]|>println
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/38DK0MzKwkBBr8YuT9dOo6AoP0VDXUHdSr1OXVNLSUFJMzpP29AKiM1ia@wKijLzSnLy/v8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
84*v
%?!\:e9*)?;:o1+:82*
ao \
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38JEq4xL1V4xxirVUkvT3toq31DbysJIiysxXyHm/38A)

Comment: It's great to see someone else enthusiastic about ><>

Comment: @mousetail Yeah it's my favourite language :) Since I don't have a ton of time to golf now I figured I'd only use ><>. Did about 20 challenges over the past few weeks before I managed to log in to my account. Don't wanna flood the feed though, so I post them sparingly, unless someone else (you) have already posted something similar.

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PyYxnysmx8JES9sq1VJL09463zDHwkhL1V7x/38A) using stack length as a counter

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX Shell Command Language + Utilities + V10 UNIX seq, 54 bytes

```sh
printf %b `seq -f'obase=8;"\";%g' 32 126|bc`|fold -w16
```

Self-explanatory: seq generates lines in the `obase=8;"\";100` format, bc turns them into lines in the `\144` format, printf expands them and pastes them together, fold wraps the output at 16 columns

There is, of course, trouble with seq. The minimal seq required here is Version 10 AT&T UNIX (and, hence, Plan 9), V8-V9 won't work since they take a **-p***picture* argument. Realistically this is not a problem since all modern systems include a V10-compatible seq, but.

Transcript of test cases:

```sh
$ cat b.sh; echo; wc -c b.sh
printf %b `seq -f'obase=8;"\";%g' 32 126|bc`|fold -w16
54 b.sh
$ ./b.sh; echo
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./
0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmno
pqrstuvwxyz{|}~
$ ./b.sh | hd
00000000  20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27  28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f  | !"#$%&'()*+,-./|
00000010  0a 30 31 32 33 34 35 36  37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e  |.0123456789:;<=>|
00000020  3f 0a 40 41 42 43 44 45  46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d  |?.@ABCDEFGHIJKLM|
00000030  4e 4f 0a 50 51 52 53 54  55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c  |NO.PQRSTUVWXYZ[\|
00000040  5d 5e 5f 0a 60 61 62 63  64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b  |]^_.`abcdefghijk|
00000050  6c 6d 6e 6f 0a 70 71 72  73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a  |lmno.pqrstuvwxyz|
00000060  7b 7c 7d 7e                                       |{|}~|
00000064
```

Here's a **100**-byte fully-standards-conformant version, same output:

```sh
i=32
printf %b $(while [ $i -le 126 ]
do
printf %s\\n 'obase=8;"\";'$i
i=$((i+1))
done|bc)|fold -w16
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `N`, \$5\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.12 bytes

```
zC6AP
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLq5zNHAMgbJhQtJKfUiyUAwA)

##### Explanation

```python
zC6AP   # Full program. No inputs.
zC      # Push the ASCII codepage as a string
  6AP   # Split into 6 chunks
        # The N flag automatically joins by newlines
        # And then it is output implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 19 bytes

```
echo _16]\u:32+i.95
```

Full program with trailing whitespace.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboWm1OTM_IV4g3NYmNKrYyNtDP1LE0hMlAFMIUA)

```
echo _16]\u:32+i.95
               i.95  NB. range 0..94
            32+      NB. offset, 32..126
          u:         NB. convert codes to chars
     _16 \           NB. for every non-overlapping length 16 slice
        ]            NB. simply return that slice
echo                 NB. return the resulting table
```

Answer (score 0):

## vim, 77 bytes

```
qqA<C-V><C-A><C-V><ESC><ESC>v0da0x0<ESC>@"0xII<C-V><C-V><ESC>A<C-V><ESC><ESC>v0d@"qxV!seq 32 126
:%norm @q
VgggJ0qq16li
<ESC>q4@q
```

`<C-V>` is 0x16. `<C-A>` is 0x01. `<ESC>` is 0x1b.

## Annotated

```
qq                                   # define macro q that changes e.g. "48" to "0" as follows:
    A<C-V><C-A><C-V><ESC><ESC>          # Change e.g. "48" to "48<INC>"
    v0d                                 # Place the above command in register "
    a0x0<ESC>@"                         # Write 0x0, then use above command to increment. Thus, "48" becomes "0x30"
    0xII<C-V><C-V><ESC>A<C-V><ESC><ESC> # Convert "0x30" to "I<C-V>x30<ESC>" (command that appends character 0x30, i.e. "0")
    v0d@"                               # Pull command into register and execute
q
xV!seq 32 126         # Populate file with numbers 32-126, one per line.
:%norm @q             # Execute macro q over each line
VgggJ                 # Join lines
0qq16li<NL><ESC>q     # Insert a newline 16 characters from the start, and record as a macro while we're at it
4@q                   # Execute that macro 4 more times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7DQUYxRTFq6zCAl0aDCQNpByaDC01NMTNoRIuigVFgRplicWqhgbKRgaGTGZaWal1@Uq@BQyBWWnp7uZVBYaGiWk8klXWjiUPj/PwA)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P1PINis/kzOXs4jT2EjH0MhMU0ddSUxMSa/MqiwxR11TR0lJk0u6sNDQrCYRSJs4FP7/DwA "V (vim) – Try It Online") for 50 bytes

Comment: @AaroneousMiller That isn't working for me when I run it in vim. Does it use `V`-specific stuff instead of just vim?

Comment: It should work if you're using the default vimrc. Try opening vim with `vim -u /etc/vim/vimrc` and see if it works then.

Comment: @AaroneousMiller It gives me a "too many arguments" error for join, map, and rand if I type it in by hand, and just gives me a bunch of blank lines if I `source!` it in. (with the default vimrc)

Comment: That's very strange, it seems to work perfectly fine for me. Out of curiosity, is your Vim up to date, and is it compiled with the default settings? Also does it work without tab auto-complete, like [this?](https://tio.run/##K/v/P1PINis/M08jN7FAoygxLz1Vw9hIx9DITFNHXUlMTEmvzKosMUddU0dJSZNLurDQ0KwmEUibOBT@/w8A "V (vim) – Try It Online")

Comment: @AaroneousMiller It appears my vim might be *too* up-to-date. [v8.1.2342](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2342) added a `rand` function, and tab completion is expanding `r` to that instead of `range`.  Switching `r<TAB>` to `rang<TAB>` makes it work. (And like the other, it's different enough from my approach to deserve its own answer.)

Comment: Gotcha. Coincidentally, I have version 8.1, so I guess it's from right before that was added.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 63 bytes

```java
v->{for(char c=31;++c<127;)System.out.print(c%16>14?c+"\n":c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY69CsIwFEb3PsWlILSUBqqiYLUOzk6CizrE2x9T06QkNwWRPnuN4vxxvnNaPvC0LZ8TSm4tHLlQ8A4ALHESCK2fmSMhWe0UktCKHbSyrqvM9qxFWUC9m4a0eNfaRPjgBnC3yPIkwW02X@fx6WWp6ph2xHojFEU4y1ZFttxjEl5VuME4H6fc@3p3l9731w7@GjrfEp3IY83lBtw0Nv6lAdSMI1Y9RcpJGX/xMRinDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç·qª>%bΓ½⌠
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80fa71a63e2562e2abf4&i=&a=1)

### Approach

- [0..126]
- Keep only 95 last elements.
- Split into chunks of 16
- Print each

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 25 bytes

```
88+sp' '~R' r[l[fo,]p9`o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/CQru4QF1BvS5IXaEoOic6LV8ntsAyIT/2/38A)

This one is pretty straightforward.  It uses a range command to generate the codepoints, the two loops to print them with a `\n` every 16 characters.

```
88+sp                     - stash the number 16
     ' '~R                - push codepoints from " " to "~" to the stack
          ' r             - push a blank (for DEL) and reverse stack
             [          ] - loop until the stack it empty
              l           - push 16 (from back up cell)
               [  ,]p     - loop 16 times...
                fo        - pull codepoint forward and print as char
                     9`o  - print a LF
```

Answer (score 0):

## [The Waterfall Model](https://esolangs.org/wiki/The_Waterfall_Model) (with output extension), 166 bytes

```
[[30000,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],[3,2,2,0,0,0,7,0],[2,2,2,0,0,0,3,0],[1,0,2,300,0,0,0,0],[66,2,0,0,302,0,9,0],[4822,2,0,0,300,5100,9,0],[9,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[29998,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc0xDsAgCAXQCzEgtCpnMQ4O7eTUNOnxKVpr9A@Sh8hT7uM6S62qKTHagbAmQ2IgC/YEQBNahLs4qwhsfmgz78cjxnZLxy0STUbYHf4dgTkM7lsjInHR9m1WfQE)

$$ \begin{array}{c|c|ccccccc}
&start&A&B&α&β&γ&out&halt\\\hline
A&3&2&2&&&&7&\\
B&2&2&2&&&&3&\\
α&1&&2&300&&&&\\
β&66&2&&&302&&9&\\
γ&4822&&&&300&5100&9&\\
out&9&&&&&&1&\\
halt&29998&&&&&&&
\end{array} $$

- A and B each (upon zeroing) add 2 to both of them, and stay 1 apart. This means one of them will be zeroing every 2 steps, and externally adding 2 to that one will switch it to the other one.
- α and β cause switches to A and to B, respectively. β has a period 2 longer than α, so the time between α and β increases by 2 each cycle, and thus the number of times A zeroes increases by 1 each cycle.
- A increments the output counter and β causes it to be output as a character and reset to 0, thus outputting an increasing sequence of characters. B increases the output waterclock by a non-output-affecting value of 3 to keep it away from zero.
- γ first zeroes after the 17th zeroing of α and 10 following zeroings of A. It causes output as a character, for a line feed (ASCII 10), and increases β by 302 – equal to α's period rather than 2 greater – so that the difference between α and β does not change for this cycle.
  γ has a period 17 times that of α, to add a line feed after every 16 other characters.
- The halt waterclock is never incremented, and simply counts down and ends the program after 100 characters (95 printable characters and 5 line feeds).

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 21 bytes

```
96,{[32+]}[/]''*16/n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39JMpzra2Eg7tjZaP1ZdXcvQTD9P6/9/AA)

Comment: -1 byte without trailing unprintable:
```95,{[32+]''+}/]16/n*```

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 16 bytes

```
⎕UCS 6 16⍴31+⍳95
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-93, 36 bytes

```
" ">:,1+:"~"1+\`v
   ^            _@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X0lByc5Kx1DbSqlOyVA7JqGMS0FBIU4BCcQ7/P8PAA)

I don't know if i can optimize this code even further than i did.

### An explanation

This code is comprised of 5 main parts:

- `" "`: Push 0x20 onto the stack.
- `:,`: Output the current character.
- `-1`: Increment the current character.
- `` :"~"1+` ``: Compare the current character with 0x7e.
- `_@`: If current character is greater than 0x7e, end the program; else loop back to the start with `^`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>89</s> 73 bytes

```kotlin
print((' '..'~').chunked(16).map{it.joinToString("")}.joinToString("\n"))
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/azf6L2jWX)

### Edits

- -16, inlined conversion to Char

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 31 bytes

```
;=a 32W>127aO+AaI%=a+1a 16"\"""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVhbc9NGFH7vr1BUiLWWothphw5WlAykoZNpcShJy7S2wavV2laRJaNLErDVv07PWd1WvoXywFi7357bfuey@Yfe0ZhF3iI5CkKXf2U@jWPl18CbzpLLKAojhT8kPHBjRXwtsxzwhkYxb@5LZ0rU2zRIvPnjuJsk4nS@ZGEQJ1HKkjDSKFkmMy824zCNGLdpBjve4t3MS3i8oIxrxf6cJmymHb/XBsPRcDCMYT3rjfTV94P3w2DU1obB6gkh7WOSLTj/CLsRT9IoUCThg85otQpS389yYY7B7A5Z@jxRqO2Y/IEzTYITqxCBR2zbpuf4oydDbOm3GacO2K5RUGP6PJgmM2LQARuRLAnBcS@YbrUqy0Q4lNu/3lze2IORlYfqT@qnfBknNPGYssBb0ByydMyN8FgTiOIdjcCHjkVPhZhCv0V1PfeP2WJ9QEdmKcvyJhojhT0sk3zNojQQYY/CeyXg9zkjMpc76XTL@g7vhBCz3gRcP507PNqBKzcB9zIMfU6DHcBqNytY9RsEI6J@Rbw8dGski9MFSjeEqA8uTShwLXdUUrLFmeK7PrfNk@K7Cdpwo1yQYfyTj@YVCKp4YDUNGA8nudeSG4eHkvHAx/xXGQUUXoWgCMkGf0qu19l0@2pEBi@O/h61j41uRXl6eIgXjDI19VZFbSRz0/micmZcOvNE5GdGxpmfzGpXDmpbDw9p49qmMk6RcQdNYJaTeZHGMw1XiZWnymX/z6u31/3Xl/1be5kVCXPl8iBZ48Bj7g/o0ZcPI/y/c/T8A4RgPQBCKBib7WOThyBgUzM@4qg38QCXhyjHYaDAXG8aoBzJk0GNGVXUzA3egcIMvgs9V@kc4P2Ullt1gsp1WRv/EXwMwvtA8SrLlFbDtNa4GXPhAinjK0X3W@k1dPXNkEJAi3ShZJ1UxUbNKeq6ElfK8zVndCqVDpJBDd4LP2rC56m/F95uwl3vTvay3sKbaFxCKeo1TWYm8CZgktRj8HvXJakXNAjCRAFVcCeK81n5wqNQBVND93/qrhU@pY/qA/GpH0r6FuH9fn21@NXqQKOnHfJNzrfb3@A9f1iEAZKUJlwYpCQh1MaAT4Fvd1wB43gERvo7KsmpfG87681ZA9Ugfk37PjTE/byXqndF/H5RUknOeRTSKCFlBcF2u5YDKoI1ou7rDEJe4fwjoWThHMzk4oipVsH4n6fk4OBaGR1ojo8GBynk2FTqOWprRGCOi4c3o/Y5GXaPjRNBK4wGMMuRiQQacFjJhxhq5sMdgtUWtiW2WrXUFv4gtUv10IpFD6yaewEwyVU@pSEQigcsTHGZuz3lyZJm420tXdjfzCOj2yGrVWetZhUDwr6ahU6MC0ChcLP0IKjWZUZ8wSn0HrkCPcL4atTay/gKJV8qLBbdFU5R9@ZzwHo0syP@KfUirqmTWCXGEkdkseVIW2zm@e6HRRQyHiPq1R/9i9ur6/5N3ZtfQQ3Y15olluQXDJN5JWbgSJ1O3LQ0q1oSr857Iuv0lUmOc8ZwnKdxPsYPF@Zj95SVs7FbzsYTW1hklqagsoPJDjq99qB3B1OFRtN0jgPHk6WrdzMFlCgT9BI6qoON1OJ5YCckk@4YA6ExwzH42kgBS2xtrEBxNs1/B3TObSf/Dapjm23OruKAZppmhaoqS17FVdSeeGGgqXoltQqPo5QjpzhKdVs1FFV3zFxG1cV1daM2XTv/cJaYXiz4a8C4lE0KVUrEp16ccOEiWUJou9irygfS2ltCU/tgkjJPYchzIFEfKEv8zwr0AoXNaARfMLP4YTCFmmTVBKEj25E0QmCqziVfbZFk8ALVHCkPiFx76jEqf29YW2mg9kPlDiVDoUx9F20VKtwDqJVSVmHAiVGFQH2jGhqxz4onmaoajv0ynUx4ZFLfD5kGA7gbYpCo1gFGdGAiN4DyDjwpiQOGf7SYDq7eQ8ZxrQtdWOyIl5yJufXOg8RXh4FKCLOZGfsevBA7hnJUT/ZlpWEkky17m1vWaN0TPwRffzx5/uPzZz@dPH/WFqsRDdxwjmGTz1@qBrXPMGS0Edoa0nrRQkiV6Hl4C6scubuBAeelmbkkcxKF8wtgwEXowqBZvJ1IrzRXvk6TFbgXCc5sspEvhZFUXrrIl4rHpfhf3h6L7aoPNZ3b4aj6uzhUFESTP3jrVVzCHlQKxFur@QBqIH@rkOixbEiZTDL6Z@TWWTW@NYJdWhYnbpgm5n0EjRsE5nlODNqI2XVTUK21kKYOh@J5WJANmHa@Q37JRoCQ3lbMGHvjd2NiVDOTbIkOFMUiUl8XNtrCt4bzRxtIfBdsQ7Y3kNiXtyGPN5DiNbAF@XRTZrjdzvcbSDF1b0GeVsiKKuURnAiqI/KZs91nprvOnO8@gyV/65nD6oxGy7xu/J3mvDjWa2Te6tFjtOdsZqQlHct3jW0BsyVYo7bgk3a1ApXS876ZyNQs3ueOXel3GsLfVcKX2D2tRtJaZC3dtpL5KhcBTd8@o1uDxTZ9/0U6JIJW2204jUeageVf@iwrGC3/SolCVitVbUbtplDgChXloUdUuba7qbkCl60ex/pzqsNUWZoAHY7oTK9N0l3sxXXD@LclV7zm0x1wEJ2yisDEcjc4gU74Ff5ZNlV@OHl31j35iV7rL@jVU5vqXap0n6lDVVX/Aw)

Unminified:

```
; = a 32
: WHILE (> 127 a)
    : OUTPUT (+ (ASCII a) (IF (% (= a (+ 1 a)) 16) "\" ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
#_odH ¬òG
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=I19vZEggrPJH)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 92 bytes

```py
print('\n'.join([''.join([chr(32+j+16*i)for j in range(16)])for i in range(6)]).rstrip(''))
```

Note that the blank looking character inside rstrip is DEL.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcixCoAgEADQX3G7M0EwwZ@phojKczjlcmnq042CaHu8ctaY2bdWhLgijAw2ZWIc4MMSBX1vknGhI71lUUkRK5l5X9EFPb1H/z1l5ahCBeECrVu7AQ)

Explanation:

```py
                [''.join([chr(32+j+16*i)for j in range(16)])for i in range(6)] # generate rows of string
      '\n'.join(                                                              ) # join with new lines
                                                                               .rstrip('') # strip the DEL out
print(                                                                                    
 ) # then print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pascal, 104 B

This source code complies with the ISO standard 7185 “Standard Pascal” (level 0).

```pascal
program p(output);var c:char;begin for c:=' 'to'~'do if ord(c)mod 16=15 then writeLn(c)else write(c)end.
```

The output lacks of trailing newline.

## Extended Pascal, 94 B

In “Standard Pascal” (ISO standard 7185) width specifiers in *have* to be *positive*.
That means the `n` in `write(123:n)` has to be ≥ 1.
“Extended Pascal”, as laid out in ISO standard 10206, permits a zero-`write`-width format specifier.
We can utilize this and “conditionally” print `chr(10)` – the newline character as used in Unixoid environments (Linux, FreeBSD, …).

```pascal
program p(output);var c:char;begin for c:=' 'to'~'do write(c,chr(10):ord(ord(c)mod 16=15))end.
```

In Pascal, the newline character is the only character that may not appear in a string literal.
Thus `chr(10)` cannot be shortened any further.

Answer (score 0):

## ARM Thumb-2 machine code (Linux), 30 bytes

```
20 24 06 a1 01 22 01 34 25 07 08 bf 02 22 04 27
01 20 00 df 0c 70 7f 2c f3 d1 00 de 20 0a
```

Put this in a **read-write-execute section** at a 4 byte aligned address.

Assembler source:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    // Store in a read-write-execute section so I don't need to address
    // a different section or use the stack for my buffer
    .section ".wtext", "awx", %progbits
    .thumb
    .globl _start
    .thumb_func
    // Aligned address is necessary for the buffer
    .p2align 2, 0
_start:
    // First char
    movs    r4, #' '
.Lloop:
    // syscall setup for write(1, .Lbuf, 1)
    movs    r0, #1
    adr     r1, .Lbuf
    movs    r2, #1
    movs    r7, #4
    // Increment r4
    adds    r4, #1
    // And test r4 & 0xF to see if the NEXT char is a multiple
    // of 16. I do this with my favorite narrow instruction, LSLS,
    // where I shift out all the other bits into a dummy register and set
    // the flags.
    lsls    r5, r4, #32 - 4
    // If so, set the length to 2 to print the newline
    // if ((r4 & 0xF) == 0) length = 2;
    it      eq
    moveq   r2, #2
    // Syscall
    svc     #0
    // Store new byte into the buffer. This is why a writable .text
    // is needed.
    strb    r4, [r1]
    // Check if we are at the end (DEL), if not, loop again
    cmp     r4, #0x7f
    bne     .Lloop
.Lexit:
    // Exit with a SIGILL crash because I don't care :)
    udf     #0
    .p2align 2, 0
    // mutable buffer
.Lbuf:
    // Current char
    .byte ' '
    // Additional newline
    .byte '\n'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 42 bytes

```arturo
loop split.every:16` `..`~`=>[print join&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?lFD2PX)

```
                   ` `..`~`                 ; a block of characters from space to tilde
     split.every:16                         ; split a block into groups of sixteen
loop                       =>[           ]  ; loop over every element in a block
                                        &   ; current element being looped over
                                    join    ; join block of chars to a string
                              print         ; print with newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 56 bytes

```
Print/@BlockMap[FromCharacterCode,32~Range~126,UpTo@16];
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work on TryItOnline due to an outdated interpreter that can't handle the `UpTo` abstraction in the `BlockMap` function call. I can offer this screenshot of my local machine: [image: Screenshot "proof"]

In case that ever gets fixed (or someone knows how to work around it), here is a TIO link anyway: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvRN/BKSc/Ods3sSDarSg/1zkjsSgxuSS1yDk/JVXH2KguKDEvPbXO0MhMJ7QgJN/B0CzW@v9/AA)

If you are not in a notebook environment the `;` at the end can be removed to save one byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
≡&p⬚@ ↯∞_16+@ ⇡95
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__4omhJnDirJpAIOKGr-KInl8xNitAIOKHoTk1Cg==)

```
≡&p⬚@ ↯∞_16+@ ⇡95
              ⇡95  # range from 0 to 94
           +@      # add space character
   ⬚@ ↯∞_16        # reshape into matrix 16 wide, filling excess with spaces
≡&p                # print each row
```